# Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estou com esse problema no meu projeto e já tentei as souluções desses posts:
[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899963/how-to-fix-22-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582664/android-studio-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1), mas nenhuma delas funcionou comigo. O projero roda perfeitamente no Android Studio 1.2, mas quando atualizei para a 1.3 começou a dar esse problema.

Esse é o meu arquivo build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.6'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.appname"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3.2"

    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.2.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'

    compile files('libs/android-smart-image-view-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"


}
```

**Esse é o erro completo:**

Error:Execution failed for task ':appName:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**Já no console do Gradle eu tenho esses erros:**

:appName:processDebugResources

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"/home/user/Desktop/projects/UMobile/trunk/uniforMobile/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"/home/user/Desktop/projects/UMobile/trunk/uniforMobile/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.","sources":[{}]}

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Você tentou dar um `clean` no projeto ?

Comment: Sim. 
No clean ele já "crasha".